# Instantiate Class Within Method With Greater Scope

Tags: c#, class, scope

So I'm making a little ESL bomb game, but I want to make a more efficient set of code. As of now I have this:

```
 public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    string pinNumber;
    Bomb bombA = new Bomb("A", 1, "A", 1, "A", "B", "C", "D", "Sentence");
    int progress;
    int wireChoice;
    string ansChoice;
    int timer = 600;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Start();

        Random _bombType = new Random();
        int bombType = 1;

        if (bombType == 1)
        {
            genBomb();
        }
        else
        {

        }

    }

    public void genBomb()
    {
        bombA.Pin = 6259;
        bombA.Serial = "G6P4LN";
        bombA.Wire = 2;
        bombA.Code = "to rearrange";
        bombA.Choice1 = "rearrange";
        bombA.Choice2 = "to rearrange";
        bombA.Choice3 = "rearranged";
        bombA.Choice4 = "rearranging";
        bombA.Question = "I purchased so many new outfits that I need ______ my closet.";
        uiUpdate();
    }

public void uiUpdate()
    {
        serialLbl.Text = bombA.Serial;
        puzzleLbl.Text = bombA.Question;
        ans1.Text = bombA.Choice1;
        ans2.Text = bombA.Choice2;
        ans3.Text = bombA.Choice3;
        ans4.Text = bombA.Choice4;
        timerLbl.Text = timer.ToString();
    }
```

I have a separate public class file for the Bomb class with public variables. However, I have to instantiate bombA in the Form2 field and redefine its variable values in the method genBomb().

I want to create bombA within that method instead, but doing so causes other methods that refer to bombA.Variable to not function because they no longer exist in that context.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scope is defined when the variable or member is *declared*, not necessarily when you create an object. You can declare the field without giving it a value:

```
Bomb bombA;
```

and initialize it in `genBomb`:

```
public void genBomb()
{

    bombA = new Bomb("A", 1, "A", 1, "A", "B", "C", "D", "Sentence");

    bombA.Pin = 6259;
    ....
```

Be aware that you need to check for a `null` value in `uiUpdate` since there's nothing preventing it from being called prior to `genBomb`.

Comment: Thanks! As a beginner I never explicitly learned that scope is defined with declaration and can always be defined later. I appreciate the help! Though I'm not sure how to go about adding a null check. How would uiUpdate be called if uiUpdate() is only called after the bombA values are declared?

Comment: What i mean if you need to ad something like `if (bombA = null)` to see if `bombA` is null before trying to access its properties or methods, otherwise you'll get a null reference exception.